# openapi-genrator using mustache template should generate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

does anyone have sample project or information on in react/UI how to use mustache template for openapi generator which should generate service file according to openapi3 spec.json  ?

Comment: Ganesh, can you provide any examples of what you have already tried that doesn't work? It's not exactly clear what you are asking.

Comment: i am working on react project .i was using swagger-js-codegen for generating service files using mustache templates. But now i need to support openapi 3 as well. since swagger-js-codegen doesnt support openapi3 .i need to use similar library like swagger-js-codegen which will also take in mustache template and generate service file.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear before.  I have not heard of mustache templates, for example.  I'm wondering if you could provide some code examples and evidence of what you have tried.